# Visual Studio .Net MAUI > no .net 6 in frame selection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui

I will create a new .netMAUI project in visual studio, but when choosing the framework, there is only .NET 8 and no .NET 6.

[image]

How do I view .Net 6 while adding a new project?

-I installed options related to .net 6 from the Installer.
-I installed from SDK (it appears in CMD > dotnet --list-sdks)

[image]

Comment: I don't currently know the answer, but I would generally not recommend doing that, since MAUI has _significantly_ improved from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0. I wouldn't recommend starting a new project with the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

When creating the project, select .Net 8 and create the project. Then, if you change "Targer Runtime" to NET 6 from Properties > Android Targets, it will run on Android Lollipop 5.0.

By the way, thank you for your comment > @PMF

[image]

Comment: 1. You can change `Target Runtime` to NET 6 from Properties > Android Targets in VS. 2. Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.